# Mutable list of mutabale non-integral types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, mutable, hmatrix

I'm trying to parse a huge 3d-data array of complex values from binary. Later this should become `l` matrices (`n x m`). Since I'm going to work on these matrices, I'm limited to matrix libraries - hmatrix seems to be promising.
The data layout is not in my requried format, so I have to jump around in positions `(i,j,k) -> (k,i,j)`, where `i` and `j` are elements of `n` and `m` and `k` element of `l`.

I think the only way to read in this in is my using mutables, otherwise I'll end up with several Terrabytes of garbage. My idea was to use boxed mutual arrays or vectors of mututal matrices (STMatrix from Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Devel), so I end up with something like:

```
data MVector s (STMatrix s t)
```

But I'm not sure how to use them correctly:
I can modify one single element of the MVector with modify:

```
modify :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> (a -> a) -> Int -> m ()
```

or use modifyM (Strange: in stack vector-0.12.3.0 does not have modifyM...)

```
modifyM :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> (a -> m a) -> Int -> m ()
```

so I could use the function call `(a -> a)` to a runST-routine to modify the SMatrix. I'm not sure, if I should put an ST in an IO (?)

Nevertheless - I think, this should work but is only useful, when I want to modify the whole Matrix, calling this `(a->a)`-routine `n x m x l`- times will be a little bit overhead (Maybe it will be optimized out...).
So I'll end up, in marshalling the Array, modify the content via pointers `(i,j,k) -> (k,i,j)` and read everything Matrix by Matrix - but this does not feel right and I wanted to avoid such dirty tricks.

Do you have any ideas of a way to do this a little but more ...clean?
Ty

**Edit:**
Thx to K. A. Buhr. His solution works so far. Now, I'm only running into some performance impacts. If I compare the solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import Data.List
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable as VSM

-- Create an l-length list of n x m hmatrix Matrices
toMatrices :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [C] -> [Matrix C]
toMatrices l n m dats = map (reshape m) $ VS.createT $ do
  mats <- V.replicateM l $ VSM.unsafeNew (m*n)
  sequence_ $ zipWith (\(i,j,k) x ->
      VSM.unsafeWrite (mats V.! k) (loc i j) x) idxs (dats ++ repeat 0)
  return $ V.toList mats

  where idxs = (,,) <$> [0..n-1] <*> [0..m-1] <*> [0..l-1]
        loc i j = i*m + j

test1 = toMatrices 1000 1000 100 (fromIntegral <$> [1..])

main = do
  let !a = test1
  print "done"
```

With the simpliest C-code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{

    const int n = 1000;
    const int m = 1000;
    const int l = 100;

    double *src = malloc(n*m*l * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < n*m*l; i++) {
        src[i] = (double)i;
    }

    double *dest = malloc(n*m*l * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
                dest[k*n*m+i*m+j] = src[i*m*l+j*l+k];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("done: %f\n", dest[n*m*l - 1]); // Need to access the array, otherwise it'll get lost by -O2
    free(src);
    free(dest);
}
```

Both compiled with -O2 give following performance guesses:

```
real    0m5,611s
user    0m14,845s
sys 0m2,759s
```

vs.

```
real    0m0,441s
user    0m0,200s
sys 0m0,240s
```

This are approx 2 magnitudes per-core performance. From profiling I learn that

```
      VSM.unsafeWrite (mats V.! k) (loc i j) x
```

is the expensive function.
Since I'll use this procedure in a minute-like intervall, I want to keep the parsing time as low as the disk access time. I'll see, if I can speed this up

PS: This is for some tests, if I could move usual DSP from C-like to Haskell

**Edit2 :**
Ok, this is what I get after sum trying:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main where

import Data.List
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable as VSM
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

-- Create an l-length list of n x m hmatrix Matrices
toMatrices :: Int -> Int -> Int -> VS.Vector C -> V.Vector (Matrix C)
toMatrices l n m dats =
  V.map (reshape m) newMat
   where
    newMat = VS.createT $
      V.generateM l $ \k -> do
      curMat <- VSM.unsafeNew (m * n)
      VS.mapM_
        (\i ->
           VS.mapM_
             (\j -> VSM.unsafeWrite curMat (loc i j) (dats VS.! (oldLoc i j k)))
            idjs)
        idis
      return curMat
    loc i j = i * m + j
    oldLoc i j k = i * m * l + j * l + k
    !idis = VS.generate n (\a->a)
    !idjs = VS.generate m (\a->a)

test1 = toMatrices 100 1000 1000 arr
  where
    arr = VS.generate (1000 * 1000 * 100) fromIntegral :: VS.Vector C

main = do
  let !a = test1
  print "done"
```

It gives something about:

```
real    0m1,816s
user    0m1,636s
sys 0m1,120s
```

, so ~4 times slower than C code. I think I can live with this.
I guess, I'm destroying all the stream-functionality of the vector with this code. If there are any suggestions to have them back by a comparable speed, I would be grateful!

Comment: Don't understand why you think you need them to be mutable.  You don't trust the garbage collector?  Usually garbage can be collected incrementally, so you don't need to keep the whole structure in memory at once.

Comment: Nothing about your description screams to me that you need anything mutable. Have you considered reading the whole thing into a single 3-dimensional array with `k` as the first index? [`Data.Array.listArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array.html) should be able to create that from a simple list comprehension over your input coordinates and data. Then if you like you can just map over the rows (hyper-rows?) of the array, and convert each to a matrix once you're done reading the data.

Comment: @luqui I think the question is worried not exactly about the cost of collecting garbage, but about the possible n^2 nature of a process that creates a large zero matrix, then makes a copy of that large matrix with one element changed, and so on for each element. I don't know if the matrix library does enough sharing to not worry about that, but if it is a concern then it doesn't really matter how good the GC is.

Comment: @amalloy thx. for clarifying. Yes and indeed, I am a little bit concerned about the performance impacts.

Comment: @amalloy 2nd: Using Data.Array.listArray instead of the the ptr-gymnastics is a very good and simple solution...thanks!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Could you include a concrete description of the relevant parts of the data format? Could you explain what structure you're trying to build a bit more fully, and maybe give some pseudo-code? I would be surprised if you really need mutation just to read in some matrices from a file, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @dfeuer I hope the answer from K. A. Buhr below explains the problem quite well. In the first example the first test works, the second fails easily because out of memory. The second example resolves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a "huge" set of data in `i`-major, `j`-middling, `k`-minor order, and you want to load it into matrices indexed by `k` whose elements have `i`-indexed rows and `j`-indexed columns, right?  So, you want a function something like:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

-- load into "l" matrices of size "n x m"
toMatrices :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [C] -> [Matrix C]
toMatrices l n m dats = ...
```

Note that you've written `n x m` matrices above, associating `i` with `n` and `j` with `m`.  It would be more usual to flip the roles of `n` and `m`, but I've stuck with your notation, so keep an eye on that.

If the entire data list `[C]` could fit comfortably in memory, you could do this immutably by writing something like:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

toMatrices :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [C] -> [Matrix C]
toMatrices l n m = map (reshape m . fromList) . transpose . chunksOf l
```

This breaks the input data into `l`-sized chunks, transposes them into `l` lists, and converts each list to a matrix.  If there was some way to force all the `Matrix C` values in parallel, this could be done with one traversal through the data, without the need to hold on to the whole list.  Unfortunately, the individual `Matrix C` values can only be forced one-by-one, and the whole list needs to be kept around until all of them can be forced.

So, if the "huge" `[C]` list is too big for memory, you're probably right that you need to load the data into a (partially) mutable structure.  The code is somewhat challenging to write, but it's not too bad in its final form.  I believe the following will work:

```
import Data.List
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable as VSM

-- Create an l-length list of n x m hmatrix Matrices
toMatrices :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [C] -> [Matrix C]
toMatrices l n m dats = map (reshape m) $ VS.createT $ do
  mats <- V.replicateM l $ VSM.unsafeNew (m*n)
  sequence_ $ zipWith (\(i,j,k) x ->
      VSM.unsafeWrite (mats V.! k) (loc i j) x) idxs (dats ++ repeat 0)
  return $ V.toList mats

  where idxs = (,,) <$> [0..n-1] <*> [0..m-1] <*> [0..l-1]
        loc i j = i*m + j

test1 = toMatrices 4 3 2 (fromIntegral <$> [1..24])
test2 = toMatrices 1000 1000 100 (fromIntegral <$> [1..])

main = do
  print $ test1
  print $ norm_Inf . foldl1' (+) $ test2
```

Compiled with `-O2`, the maximum residency is about 1.6Gigs, which matches the expected memory needed to hold 100 matrices of one million 16-byte complex values in memory, so that looks right.

Anyway, this version of `toMatrices` is made somewhat complicated by the use of three different vector variants.  There's `Vector` from `hmatrix`, which is the same as the immutable storable `VS.Vector` from `vector`; and then there are two more types from `vector`: the immutable boxed `V.Vector`, and the mutable storable `VSM.Vector`.

The `do`-block creates a `V.Vector` of `VSM.Vector`s and populates those with a sequence of monadic actions performed across index/value pairs.  You can load the data in any order by modifying the definition of `idxs` to match the order of the data stream.  The `do`-block returns the final `VSM.Vector`s in a list, the helper function `VS.createT` freezes them all to `VS.Vector`s (i.e., `Vector` from `hmatrix`), and `reshape` is mapped across the vectors to turn them into `m`-column matrices.

Note that you'll have to take care that in your actual application, the list of data items read from the file isn't kept around by code other than `toMatrices`, either in the original text form or the parsed numeric form.  This shouldn't be too tough to get right, but you might want to test on medium-sized test input before locking up your computer on the real dataset.

Comment: If the whole list is (more than a little bit) too big to keep in memory, won't the set of partial matrices *also* be too big?

Comment: Well, I'm thinking of the case where the unboxed matrices can fit comfortable in memory but the input boxed list plus list overhead *on top* of the output unboxed matrices is too big.

Comment: Yepp, that is exactly my problem. My concrete numbers are somewhere between 2 - 8GiB (Maybe I can reduce the whole problem to 1-4GiB by using single precision). But preventing the OS from killing out-of-memory are my biggest concerns then :)